# Is it possible to automatically pass along a switch parameter in a PowerShell Function?

Tags: function, powershell, parameters, switch-statement

I created a function with some inspiration from [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-ExternalPublic-IP-c1b601bb).

It's working as expected so far but only when an Option Switch is provided when calling the function.
What I want to do is just be able type "Get-ExternalIP" without providing a switch. The function should then automatically use the -All switch. Also I'm not sure why the -All switch even works...

I've tried to set the Parameter $All = $true it's not working and VSCode tells me that it's not recommended anyways.

Is there a way to automatically pass along the -All Option Switch when the function is called without any parameters?
Would somebody be able to explain why the function returns all info if the -All switch is specified?

Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
function Get-ExternalIP {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param (
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)][switch]$Ip,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)][switch]$HostName,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)][switch]$City,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)][switch]$Region,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)][switch]$Country,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)][switch]$Location,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)][switch]$Provider,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)][switch]$PostalCode,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)][switch]$TimeZone,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)][switch]$All
  )

  $IpInfo = Invoke-RestMethod https://ipinfo.io/json

  switch ($PSBoundParameters.Values) {
    $Ip { $IpInfo.ip }
    $HostName { $IpInfo.hostname }
    $City { $IpInfo.city }
    $Region { $IpInfo.region }
    $Country { $IpInfo.country }
    $Location { $IpInfo.loc }
    $Provider { $IpInfo.org }
    $PostalCode { $IpInfo.postal }
    $TimeZone { $IpInfo.timezone }
    Default { $IpInfo }

  }

}

Get-ExternalIP
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the `$PSBoundParameters.Keys` as your switches are properly named to match the returned info:

```
function Get-ExternalIP {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][switch]$Ip,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][switch]$HostName,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][switch]$City,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][switch]$Region,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][switch]$Country,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][switch]$Location,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][switch]$Provider,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][switch]$PostalCode,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][switch]$TimeZone,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][switch]$All
    )
    $IpInfo = Invoke-RestMethod https://ipinfo.io/json
    if ($All) { return $IpInfo }

    # exclude Common Parameters
    $commonParams = 'Debug','ErrorAction','ErrorVariable','InformationAction','InformationVariable','OutVariable',
                    'OutBuffer','PipelineVariable','Verbose','WarningAction','WarningVariable','WhatIf','Confirm'

    $items = (@($PSBoundParameters.Keys) | Where-Object { $commonParams -notcontains $_ }) -replace
             'Location', 'loc' -replace 'Provider', 'org' -replace 'PostalCode', 'postal'

    $IpInfo | Select-Object $items
}
```

---

As [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) commented, there is a much better way of retrieving the used switches than shown in the above code.

Instead of filtering out the known Common Parameters, it makes more sense to check the $PSBoundParameter keys against the properties returned in the $IpInfo object.

```
$items = ($PSBoundParameters.Keys -replace 'Location', 'loc' -replace 'Provider', 'org' -replace 'PostalCode', 'postal').Where({ $_ -in $IpInfo.psobject.Properties.Name })
```

Comment: @mklement0 Oh yes, a much better way. I didn't even think of that. About the output. It is not really clear what the OP wants:  an array of values or an object with properties. In his/her code, the return is an array of values **except** when the Default option kicks in. Then it is an object.. Personally, I would always want the object outcome.

Comment: I agree that the wrapper is probably the better approach (except if the typical use case is to use only _one_ switch), but I think it's always worth _pointing out in the answer_ when a solution involves a behavioral change from the code in the question, even - and perhaps especially then - if it is a change for the better.

Comment: P.S.: I just noticed that your solution relies on a surprising, undocumented behavior of `Select-Object`: with a an _empty array_ of properties to select, it passes the input object _through_ (this happens if _no_ switch is passed as opposed to `-All`); e.g., `(gi / | select @()).GetType().FullName`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and changing the function. It works just like I wanted to. I've also tried the one Mathias R. Jessen posted and it also works for me too. I will study both variants and decide which one fits my purpose the best. Thank you.

Comment: @mozzie Thanks for the nice feedback and for posting this interesting question.

Answer (score 3):

You could use parameter sets to default to the `All` option:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Everything')]
param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Something')][switch]$Ip,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Something')][switch]$HostName,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Something')][switch]$City,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Something')][switch]$Region,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Something')][switch]$Country,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Something')][switch]$Location,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Something')][switch]$Provider,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Something')][switch]$PostalCode,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Something')][switch]$TimeZone,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Everything')][switch]$All
)

# set up dictionary to hold the switch-name-to-ipinfo-names
$Options = [Ordered]@{
  'Ip' = 'ip'
  'HostName' = 'hostname'
  'City' = 'city'
  'Region' = 'region'
  'Country' = 'country'
  'Location' = 'loc'
  'Provider' = 'org'
  'PostalCode' = 'postal'
  'TimeZone' = 'timezone'
}

$IpInfo = Invoke-RestMethod https://ipinfo.io/json

# Select all options
$selected = $Options.Keys
if($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -ne 'Everything'){
    # 1 or more switches were passed, select only those options
    $selected = $selected.Where({$PSBoundParameters[$_]})
}

# Create a new object with the selected options as properties
$properties = [ordered]@{}
foreach($prop in $selected){
  $properties[$prop] = $IpInfo.($Options[$prop])
}

# return the new object
return [pscustomobject]$properties
```

By using the parameter set name to determine whether to output everything (and then return), the behavior is the same regardless of whether the user passes `-All`, or no switches at all.

Comment: Nicely done; one thing to note: the function in the question just outputs _values_ if one or more switches are passed - they're not wrapped in a custom object, unlike what your function does.

Answer (score 2):

[Mathias R. Jessen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60800639/45375) and [Theo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60800641/45375) provide elegant solutions; let me complement them with an answer to your specific question:

> Would somebody be able to explain why the function returns all info if the `-All` switch is specified?

Your `switch` statement has a `Default` branch, which is invoked if none of the other branches' conditions are met; **since you don't have a branch for the `-All` switch value, the `Default` handler kicks in *if*

`-All` was specified**.

By contrast, **if you don't pass *any* argument, the `switch` statement is never entered**, because, for *collection-valued* input, the `switch` statement implicitly *loops over* the elements of that collection.
With no arguments passed, `$PSBoundParameters.Values` is an *empty collection*, so there is nothing to enumerate.

The parameter-set approach in Mathias' answer is the simplest solution to this problem, which has the added advantage of making the `-All` switch and the specific property-name switches mutually exclusive.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation. It all makes sense now.

Answer (score -1):

If you print out what $psboundparameters.values is, you'll see it's empty when you don't use "-all", otherwise it has one value of $true.

Comment: That's not sufficient, because _common parameters_ too are reflected in `$PSBoundParameters`, so checking `$PSBoundParameters.Count -eq 0` would give you a false negative if, say, `-Verbose` is the only switch passed.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but You should write a broad description of your answer and elaborate much on it.

Comment: @WasifHasan It was I who down-voted. While the answer is certainly light on explanation, its primary problem is the conceptual flaw that I've pointed out.